# What is a good iPhone UI framework for a chess like game?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, core-animation, core-graphics, chess

I am trying to develop a chess like game for iphone/ipad, I have developed the internal game logic using objective-c and c++ , that's fine but I am wondering what's the possible ways to develope a good GUI on iphone/ipad ?

As far as I know I could use Core Graphic, cocos2d.

Are there any more ? 
And which one might be best suitable for chess like game?
(e.g display a fixed board, add chess piece to the board, remove piece from board, move piece around on board)

If my question was causing come confusing, I have rephrased it, hope this makes it a bit clearer.
Many thanks

Comment: why this is NOT a real question ? I am asking is there any more good GUI framework that I can use and which is is best for a chess like game, there are two specific questions.

Comment: Anyone care to comment about the downvote ?

Comment: I have rephrased my question if it wasn't clear enough ...

Comment: This is a genuine question and ppl are giving useful answers & links, why those downvote ???

Comment: the edit should help now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For game frameworks, the obvious one is [cocos2d](http://cocos2d.org/).

Having almost finished a - relatively - simple 2d game, I would highly recommend using a framework like cocos2d. With Core Animation you can do a lot of amazing stuff. However, for game type scenarios, you hit problems that Core Animation doesn't solve.

For example, what if the user gets a call during the game right in the middle of an animation? You'll have to handle all that manually. I mean, you'll have to check the state of the`presentationLayer`, update the model layer, save all the state, then reconstruct it all when the app moves to the foreground again.

For this sort of issues, I'd seriously consider a game framework.

There are alternatives to cocos2d, e.g. [Kobold2D](http://www.kobold2d.com/display/KKSITE/Home). So definitely have a look around.

Comment: +1, Max, thanks for the nice insight. I have started with cocos2d a week ago and I did made a few nice test demo but I didn't know enough to choose between cocos2d and core animation/graphic for my potential game.And I don't want to invent the wheel if there are more good iphone UI framework out there.

Comment: take my advice checkout cocos2d! I started doing it by hand and although I'm glad to have learnt so much, it is an extraordinary amount of work. I'm keen to checkout cocos2d now to see how much effort it will save for the next one.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of GUI apis.

[CoconutKit](https://github.com/defagos/CoconutKit) - When designing components, I strongly emphasize on clean and documented interfaces, as well as on code quality. My goal is to create components that are easy to use, reliable, and which do what they claim they do, without nasty surprises. You should never have to look at a component implementation to know how it works, this should be obvious just by looking at its interface. I also strive to avoid components that leak or crash. If those are qualities you love to find in libraries, then you should start using CoconutKit now! Moreover, CoconutKit will never use any private API and will therefore always be AppStore friendly.

[Three20](http://three20.info/) - Three20 is a open source Objective-C library used by dozens of well-known brands in the App Store, including Facebook, Posterous, Pulse, Meetup.com, and SCVNGR. Three20 provides powerful view controllers such as the Launcher, the popular Photo Browser, and internet-aware tables.

[tapku](http://tapku.com) - Tapku Library is an open source iOS framework built for iPhone & iPad. The framework includes popular API's including coverflow, calendar grid and chart view. The framework also has tidbits of code that will make iPhone and iPad development all the more enjoyable and faster. Integrating the framework is easy and can be incorportated right into your applications now. Try out the demo to see some of the things you can take advantage of in the framework.

Direct comments from their sites.

Comment: Thanks for the link but could u add  some comments on those GUI apis ? pro& cons.

Comment: Those answered my 1st question, but any comments about the chess like game ? I probably don't need any heavy animation, which one would be suitable for it ?

Comment: Personally all I would just load images and use UIView Animation when a move is called. Not work about GUI based APIs considering this is a rather simple image and animation event.

Comment: +1, thanks for the suggestion. Max suggested coscos2d which could handle more like a phone calls during game easily. But I am also want to consider Core Animation bcos that might have better performance over cocos2d over a simple chess like game ??

Comment: I thought Cocoa2d was common knowledge.